# Angular How to patch value in the form array

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am using Angular8 and reactive forms. My ngOnInit is:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.makeForm = this.fb.group(
    year: ['', Validators.required],
    amount: ['', Validators.required],
    desc: ['', Validators.required],
    details: new FormArray([
      this.det(),
    ]
  );
}

det() {
  return new FormGroup({
    for: new FormControl(''),
    remarks: new FormControl('')
  });
}
```

I have the data from the backend to patch the array:

```json
 {
  "amount": 9000,
  "year": 1996,
  "id": 1,
  "desc": "P1",
  "details": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "remarks": "ok",
      "for": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": 24,
      "remarks": "OK",
      "for": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": 25,
      "remarks": "OK",
      "for": "1"
    }
  ]
 }
```

I commonly patch the values with this method:

```js
getppredit() {
  let data:any = this.shareService.ParentShare.value;
  let id = data.id;
  this.dataService.getdataEdit(id)
    .subscribe((result: any) => {
      let no = result.no;
      let year = result.year;
      this.makeForm.patchValue({
        no: no,
        year: year
      });
  });
}
```

The above code is used for normal patch, but how to patch the value inside of an array dynamically using Angular8's reactive forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one here

```js
    getppredit(){
      let data:any = this.shareService.ParentShare.value
      let id = data.id 
      this.dataService.getdataEdit(id)
        .subscribe((result: any)  => {
          let no = result.no;
          let year= result.year
          this.makeForm.patchValue({
              no     : no,
              year: year
              })

          //initialize empty array
          this.getFormArray() = new FormArray([]);

          //create needed formGroups and inside each formGroup all formControls
          for (let detail of result.details) {
            
            let idControl: FormControl = new FormControl('');
            let requestForControl: FormControl = new FormControl('');
            let remarkControl: FormControl = new FormControl('');

            idControl.setValue(detail.id);
            ForControl.setValue(detail.requestFor);
            remarkControl.setValue(detail.remark);

            this.getFormArray().push(new FormGroup({
              id: idControl,
              For: requestForControl,
              remark: remarkControl}));
           }

        })//end of subscribe
     
     }
    
        getFormArray(): FormArray{
            return this.makeForm.get('details') as FormArray;
          }
```

Form Arrays are usually intended to have dynamic data. Therefore you must first create your dynamic form controls inside the form array (after you have received your response) and then put values inside.

Comment: How to detect the valuechanges in this requestfor?

Comment: How to push to the existance array @Panagiwths Mpougioukos

Comment: @Madhav the existing array can be [pushed to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) using `array.push()`. See my answer above

Comment: @Madhav you use this method that I have in my answer getFormArray() to get a reference to your existent array and then you use push to push a new element

Comment: @Madhav You can use if you want getFormArray().push(dat()) to use your dat() however the form that you will push will have empty values and not the values from the json response. If you want to have those values you must see what I have done in the answer

Comment: Ya thanks man.. Now I understand and thanks. I got the solution and learned from it

Answer (score 2):

here's how i would do it using [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray), which **tracks the value and validity state of an array of FormControl, FormGroup or FormArray instances**:

```js
export class Component implements OnInit {

  // initialize the FormArray with an empty array!
  formArray: FormArray = new FormArray([]);
  makeForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.makeForm = this.fb.group({
      no: ['', Validators.required],
      year: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  getParEdit() {
    ...
    this.dataService.getDataEdit(id).subscribe(result => {
      const { no, year, details } = result;
      this.makeForm.patchValue({ no, year });

      if (details.length) {
        details.forEach(detail => {
          this.formArray.push(
            this.fb.group({
              id: new FormControl({ value: detail.id }),
              requestFor: new FormControl({ value: detail.requestFor }),
              remark: new FormControl({ value: detail.remark }),
            });
          );
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

you can dynamically create the `FormGroup` for each `detail` iteration, as well as the `FormControl`s in each.

Comment: How to push value in this array? det(){
      return new FormGroup({
        requestfor     : new FormControl(''),
        remarks        : new FormControl(''),
        // file_id        : new FormControl(''),
    })}

Comment: how to push value in exist array

Comment: @Madhav Not sure what you're trying to ask. That is not an array, that is a `FormGroup`. The example I provided above shows how to push a `FormGroup` into a `FormArray`.

Comment: ya I understand now and thanks man and I learned from this